# How to convert a loop into a list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How can I write this loop using list comprehension?

```
t = [i.find_all('li') for i in soup.select('div.col.col-7-12')]
Des = []
for i in t:
    r = []
    Des.append(r)
    for j in i:
        n = j.text
        r.append(n)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t = [i.find_all('li') for i in soup.select('div.col.col-7-12')] 
Des = [] 
for i in t: 
    r = [] 
    Des.append(r) 
    for j in i: 
        n = j.text 
        r.append(n)
```

Replace one loop:

```
t = [i.find_all('li') for i in soup.select('div.col.col-7-12')] 
Des = [] 
for i in t:
    r = [j.text for j in i]
```

Replace both loops:

```
t = [i.find_all('li') for i in soup.select('div.col.col-7-12')] 
Des = [[j.text for j in i] for i in t]
```

Or:

```
Des = [[j.text for j in i] for i in [i.find_all('li') for i in soup.select('div.col.col-7-12')]]
```

However just because you can replace something with a long list comprehension doesnt mean you should, I think in this case two two-liner I wrote is still alright to read (could use some more clear variable names), the one-liner is definitely an overkill and super hard to read.

Comment: @PullanwarOm, please accept the answer by 'ewz93' if it worked for you. It encourages! Thanks!